# Play and Pause using the same button

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I want to make it only one button that has two function. First click I want to play it and second click I want to pause it. And when I click it again It continues where it left off.

JAVA SIDE;

MediaPlayer ocean;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sound);
    ocean=MediaPlayer.create(Sound.this,R.raw.ocean);
}
public void play(View v){
    ocean.start();
}
public void pause(View V){
    ocean.pause();
}}
```

ACTIVITY SIDE:

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/play"
    android:layout_width="165dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="285dp"
    android:background="@drawable/oceansound"
    android:onClick="play"
    android:text=""/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a flag that indicates if the player is on or off:

```
Boolean isOn = false;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sound);
    ocean=MediaPlayer.create(Sound.this,R.raw.ocean);
}
public void play(View v){
    if (!isOn) {
        ocean.start();
        isOn = true;
    } else {
        ocean.pause();
        isOn = false;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you have ocean is MediaPlayer object, you can check if the song is playing by ocean.isPlaying(), hope it will help you.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    MediaPlayer ocean;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sound);

        ocean = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ocean);
    }

    public void play(View view) {
        if (ocean.isPlaying()) {
            ocean.pause();
        } else {
            ocean.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, use a checker variable to track the action.

Create a global variable `isPlay` in int / boolean, in your `play`, make a if statement to check whether it is playing or in pause, if playing, `ocean.pause();`, set the button background to pause and vice versa.

Hope it helps